# How to set connect/read timeout in the Spring's `RestClient`?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, client

How to set a connect/read timeout in the Spring's [`RestClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.1.0/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClient.html)?

This client has been added in the Spring Framework 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) where you will set connection and read timeout and then you will be able to set it to `RestClient` using provided builder.

```
public Object exampleMethod(Object object) {

        RestClient restClient = RestClient
                .builder()
                .requestFactory(getClientHttpRequestFactory())
                .build();
        //usage of restClient with timeout.
        restClient.get();
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(100);
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(70);
        return clientHttpRequestFactory;
    }
```

Comment: This example is tightly bound to the Apache Http client because the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` is from there. Is there another, more generic way to set timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is also trying to take advantage of Spring's `SslBundle`, defining it all in a `ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings` object is what worked for me:

```
@Bean
public RestClient restClient(RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder, SslBundles sslBundles) {
    ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings requestFactorySettings = new ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings(
            Duration.ofSeconds(30),
            Duration.ofSeconds(30),
            sslBundles.getBundle("mybundle"));

    return restClientBuilder
            .requestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(requestFactorySettings))
            .build();
}
```